# Not able to get working linq subquery

Tags: wcf, linq, c#-4.0

I have below sql query which i am trying to convert to Linq but cant get it exactly to work.

```
  select l.nid,
         l.sName,
         l.language,
         coalesce(p.kLanguage, 0) kLanguage

   from vLanguage l
        left join
             (
                select pl.kLanguage, 
                       p.nid,
                       p.sName

                from vProductLanguage pl
                    left join vProduct p 
                           on pl.kProduct = p.nid
                where p.nid = 1
             ) p
  on l.nid = p.kLanguage
  where l.bClosed =0
```

I have managed so for here in my WCF service

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "ProductLanguageList")]
    public List<LookUpProductLanguage> GetProductLanguageList()
    {
        var passedProductId = int.Parse("12");
        var query = from languageEntity in _languageEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
                    join subQueryResult in (from productLanguageEntity in _productLanguageEntityRepository.AsQueryable() join productEntity in _productRepository.AsQueryable() on productLanguageEntity.LanguageProductId equals productEntity.Id into joinedProductLanguage
                                            from productLanguageJoin in joinedProductLanguage.DefaultIfEmpty() where productLanguageJoin.Id.Equals(passedProductId)
                                            select new {LanguageId = productLanguageEntity.LanguageId}
                                           ) on languageEntity.Id equals  subQueryResult.LanguageId

        return null;
    }
```

For the moment i have returned null but would want to return columns mentioned in sql query. I get error near line join subQueryResult "The type arguments cannot be inferred from query". What am i doing here? Please correct me as i am sure i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Try adding `.ToList()` at the end of your query (wrap the entire query in parantheses first - like this `var query = (from ...).ToList();`

Comment: @Tim I am not getting option to add .ToList() even after adding parenthesis. Please help. Also my query is not completed as per my sql statement

Comment: LINQ query expression syntax needs to have a `select ...` clause at the end.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I am not finished with query. I have just posted what i had done so far. If you see my sql query and my linq query you will understand. Please help me finishing this linq query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed. Here is my query.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "ProductLanguageList")]
    public List<LookUpProductLanguage> GetProductLanguageList(GetParameters param)
    {
        var passedProductId = int.Parse(param.ProductId);
        var query = from languageEntity in _languageEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
                    join subQueryResult in
                        (from productLanguageEntity in _productLanguageEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
                         join productEntity in _productRepository.AsQueryable() on
                             productLanguageEntity.LanguageProductId equals productEntity.Id into
                             joinedProductLanguage
                         from productLanguageJoin in joinedProductLanguage.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where productLanguageJoin.Id.Equals(passedProductId)
                         select new {productLanguageEntity.LanguageId}
                        ) on languageEntity.Id equals subQueryResult.LanguageId into a
                    from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where languageEntity.Closed == 0 

                    select new LookUpProductLanguage {LanguageId = languageEntity.Id, LanguageName = languageEntity.Name,LanguageCode = languageEntity.Language,LanguageProductId = b.LanguageId  };

        return query.ToList();

    }
```

Many thanks guys who put efforts in trying to answer me.